# Android get Images from Picasso to Bitmap Array

Tags: android, bitmap, picasso

I want to get a Bitmap[] from my String[] with links. But this doesn't work as I want. I have this Method:

```
private Bitmap[] getBitmaps(String[] images){
    ArrayList<Bitmap> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
        ImageView img = new ImageView(getContext());
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams x = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        img.setLayoutParams(x);
        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(MainPostAdapter.USER_URL+images[i]+".png").into(img, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                temp.add(BitmapRes.drawableToBitmap(img.getDrawable()));
                movableBackgroundContainer.removeView(img);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {

            }
        });
        movableBackgroundContainer.addView(img);
    }
    return temp.toArray(new Bitmap[temp.size()]);
}
```

The problem is I get a null Array because it adds the Bitmap to the list after the onSuccess function. How can I now wait until all onSuccess added the bitmaps and then return?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `get()` function of Picasso does what you're looking for. It downloads a Bitmap rather than load an image into an ImageView. Note that Picasso's `get()` method cannot be called on the main thread. My example uses an AsyncTask to download images on a separate thread.

```
    String[] images = new String[] {"http://path.to.image1.jpg", "http://path.to.image2.jpg"};
    new AsyncTask<String[], Void, List<Bitmap>>() {
        @Override
        protected List<Bitmap> doInBackground(String[]... params) {
            try {
                List<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
                for (int i = 0; i < params[0].length; ++i) {
                    bitmaps.add(Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(params[0][i]).get());
                }
                return bitmaps;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(List<Bitmap> bitmaps) {
            if (bitmaps != null) {
                // Do stuff with your loaded bitmaps
            }
        }
    }.execute(images);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could increase an integer every time on success until the integer equals to the images.lengh(). You could check this with a loop. And in the loop is an if clause within the return.

For example

```
int currentSuccess = 0;
```

In the loop:

```
     @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                temp.add(BitmapRes.drawableToBitmap(img.getDrawable()));
                movableBackgroundContainer.removeView(img);
                currentSuccess++;
            }
```

And for the return:

```
 while(true){
     if(currentSuccess == images.length){
        return temp.toArray(new Bitmap[temp.size()]);
     }
}
```

Hope that helps.